# How do I write a Ruby method to handle zero, one, or many inputs?

Tags: ruby, idioms

I've got a Ruby method like the following:

```
# Retrieve all fruits from basket that are of the specified kind.
def fruits_of_kind(kind)
  basket.select { |f| f.fruit_type == kind.to_s }
end
```

Right now, you can call this like:

```
fruits_of_kind(:apple)    # => all apples in basket
fruits_of_kind('banana')  # => all bananas in basket
```

and so on.

How do I change the method so that it will correctly handle iterable inputs as well as no inputs and nil inputs? For example, I'd like to be able to support:

```
fruits_of_kind(nil) # => nil
fruits_of_kind(:apple, :banana)    # => all apples and bananas in basket
fruits_of_kind([:apple, 'banana']) # => likewise
```

Is this possible to do idiomatically? If so, what's the best way to write methods so that they can accept zero, one, or many inputs?

Comment: I know this question was asked years ago, but... would you consider returning `[]` instead of `nil`? It could make life easier for your callers if they can always iterate on the return value of your method and don't need to check for `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def fruits_of_kind(kind)
    return nil if kind.nil?

    result = []

    ([] << kind).flatten.each{|k| result << basket.select{|f| f.fruit_type == k.to_s }}

    result
end
```

The 'splat' operator is probably the best way to go, but there are two things to watch out for: passing in nil or lists. To modify Pesto's solution for the input/output you'd like, you should do something like this:

```
def fruits_of_kind(*kinds)
  return nil if kinds.compact.empty? 

  basket.select do |fruit|
    kinds.flatten.each do |kind|
      break true if fruit.fruit_type == kind.to_s
    end == true #if no match is found, each returns the whole array, so == true returns false
  end
end
```

If you pass in nil, the * converts it to [nil]. If you want to return nil instead of an empty list, you have to compact it (remove nulls) to [], then return nil if it's empty.

If you pass in a list, like [:apple, 'banana'], the * converts it to [[:apple, 'banana']]. It's a subtle difference, but it's a one-element list containing another list, so you need to flatten kinds before doing the "each" loop. Flattening will convert it to [:apple, 'banana'], like you expect, and give you the results you're looking for.

**EDIT**: Even better, thanks to Greg Campbell:

```
   def fruits_of_kind(basket, kind)
       return nil if kind.nil?

       kind_list = ([] << kind).flatten.map{|kind| kind.to_s}

       basket.select{|fruit| kind_list.include?(fruit) } 
   end
```

OR (using splat)

```
   def fruits_of_kind(*kinds)
       return nil if kinds.compact.empty?

       kind_list = kinds.flatten.map{|kind| kind.to_s}

       basket.select{|fruit| kind_list.include?(fruit.fruit_type) } 
   end
```

Comment: I think that's almost what I want, except that I need "result +=", not "result <<".

Comment: This handles all of the cases I described above correctly and it seems the most idiomatic.

Comment: The "<<" just appends the items to the array. It's the same as "+=". I'd honestly either use the second one I wrote (modified from Pesto's), and possibly change your output expectations to expect an empty list ([]) instead of nil. Still need to flatten it, though.

Comment: You could make this more efficient (and readable, imo) by doing the following: kind_list = kinds.flatten.map {|kind| kind.to_s}; basket.select {|fruit| kind_list.include?(fruit.fruit_type)} (apologies for the formatting, we really need to be able to format code in comments)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the Ruby splat operator, which wraps all remaining arguments into an Array and passes them in:

```
def foo (a, b, *c)
  #do stuff
end

foo(1, 2) # a = 1, b = 2, c = []
foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) #a = 1, b = 2, c = [3, 4, 5]
```

In your case, something like this should work:

```
def fruits_of_kind(*kinds)
  kinds.flatten!
  basket.select do |fruit|
    kinds.each do |kind|
      break true if fruit.fruit_type == kind.to_s
    end == true #if no match is found, each returns the whole array, so == true returns false
  end
end
```

---

### EDIT

I changed the code to flatten kinds so that you can send in a list.  This code will handle entering no kinds at all, but if you want to expressly input `nil`, add the line `kinds = [] if kinds.nil?` at the beginning.

Comment: Doesn't look like it handles the case where he passes in a list, so you may need to flatten kinds. Otherwise, from your first example, foo(1,2,[3,4,5]) will have c == [[3,4,5]], and the each won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Use the VARARGS feature of Ruby.

```
# Retrieve all fruits from basket that are of the specified kind.
# notice the * prefix used for method parameter
def fruits_of_kind(*kind)
  kind.each do |x|
    puts x
  end
end

fruits_of_kind(:apple, :orange)
fruits_of_kind()
fruits_of_kind(nil)
```

-sasuke

Comment: Will this handle the case of fruits_of_kind([:apple, 'banana'])?

Answer (score 0):

There's a nicely expressive use of splat as an argument to array creation that handles your last example:

```
def foo(may_or_may_not_be_enumerable_arg)
  arrayified = [*may_or_may_not_be_enumerable_arg]
  arrayified.each do |item|
    puts item
  end
end

obj = "one thing"
objs = ["multiple", "things", 1, 2, 3]

foo(obj)
# one thing
# => ["one thing"]

foo(objs)
# multiple
# things
# 1
# 2
# 3
# => ["multiple", "things", 1, 2, 3]
```